# Is it possible to identify if R is being run in unix or windows environment

Tags: r

I need to set up different paths for my code depending on whether it is being run in windows or unix. I currently have it set up so that the user has to change a variable "Renvironment" before running, as below.

```
Renvironment <- "windows"

if (Renvironment == "windows") {
  working_dir <- "windows_path..."
  function_library <- "windows_path..."
} else if (Renvironment == "unix") {
  working_dir <- "unix_path..."
  function_library <- "unix_path..."
}
```

I was wondering though whether there are default R environment variables that I can use instead to save the user having to remember to manually change the variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `.Platform` returns details of the platform. You can access the information about the operating system with

```
.Platform$OS.type
```

This returns either `"unix"` or `"windows"`.